# how to use class regarding table td border

Tags: html

Following code gives this result: http://prntscr.com/9ziq5j

I want this result: http://prntscr.com/9zis9g

So, this question is about how to use class on td tag!

I mean how to give a class id to the first two td's in order to make them borderless?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         td {border: 0px solid black;}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width="600" border="1">
         <tr>
            <td width="600">
               England
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="600">
               France
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="600">
               Japan
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="600">
               China
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try something like:

    table td {
        border: none;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use CSS right? So your html would then be:

```
            <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    td.England {border: 0px;}
                    td.France {border-bottom: 2px solid black;}
                    td.Japan {border-bottom: 2px solid black;}
                    td.China {border-bottom: 2px solid black;}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table width="600" border="1">

                    <tr>
                        <td width="600" class="England">
                            England
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="600" class="France">
                            France
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="600" class="Japan">
                            Japan
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="600" class="China">
                            China
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible without using css? I mean how to use border tag td inline?

Comment: @Dr. Code Uhm, probably just add a style tag like so: `<td width="600" style="border_bottom: 2px solid black;"></td>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.